# not able to initialize the init methof of servlet from spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, servlets

i have a custom servlet initialized in my spring boot app.

```
@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean<CustomServlet> servletRegistrationBean() 
{
log.info("going to initialise the servlet");
return new ServletRegistrationBean<>(new CustomServlet(), “/path1/*");
}
```

This is inside a configuration classes annotated with @Configuration, whatever i do spring does not call the init method inside the CustomServlet, although the above log is printed
This code was copied from another sample app, where exact same thing is done, but there, the servlet methods init is initialised, Any thoughts ?

spring boot starter parent version:

2.0.4.RELEASE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this;

```
@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean exampleServletBean() {
   ServletRegistrationBean bean = new ServletRegistrationBean(new CustomServlet(), "/exampleServlet/*");
   bean.setLoadOnStartup(1);
return bean;
```

}

and check this out, it may help : https://www.baeldung.com/register-servlet